# Viewport - objects disappeared in solid mode

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm not sure what happened but at some point everything lost in the solid shading mode. The cone appears to be some residue from a camera angle that was deleted earlier.
The two image are the same, only the shading is changed to material preview.
Does anyone have a guess what went wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> again to exit from *View Clipping Border* ("Allows you to define a clipping border to limit the 3D View display to a portion of 3D space")